# How to use order to do a 2d sort in R

Tags: r

An embarrassingly simple problem, but I can't seem to bend order() to my will.

I have some data pairs (x, y), I simply want to order on the x's and for the y's to follow. E.g.

```
2, 1
3, 2
1, 3
```

is reordered to:

```
1, 3
2, 1
3, 2
```

Comment: +1 for a fellow fan of the other Halo.

Answer (score 1):

In R, `order()` returns a vector of row indices. In your example:

```
> order(data$x)
[1] 3 1 2
```

Which you can interpret as “the lowest value is in row 3, the second lowest in row 1” and so on. Importantly, it does not change the data frame in any way. To obtain a data frame sorted by x using `order()`, you can then simply use:

```
> data[order(data$x),]
  x y
3 1 3
1 2 1
2 3 2
```

Comment: Sweet, nice and simple.  Many thanks.  (Yes I did mean R, and I guess you meant doesn't change the data frame.)

Comment: Yes, indeed. I fixed my answer!

Answer (score 0):

In R, order(vector) will give you the indicies in the required order. With these indicies you can reorder both your vectors.
Here are the commands for your example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(2,3,1), y=c(1,2,3) )

df[order(df$x), ]
```